# How to Concatenate Arrays of Objects and return single Array of Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, geoserver

I recieve 4 arrays from Geoserver. Each of these arrays contain objects holding lat lng data as here [geoserver response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgWvk.jpg).
I need to merge these 4 arrays in one **single Array** and then convert objects inside them into arrays. 
This was used to structure some other response from another API:

```
var routes = e.routes[0].coordinates
     var coords = routes.map(function(obj){
              return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key){
                            return obj[key];
                        })
                    })
```

This is  [routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vodec.jpg) and
this is [coords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LSIe.jpg)
and **coords is expected result** for Geoserver response.
I get my [geoserver response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgWvk.jpg). structured as shown in image after I did this:

```
function goPark(routeLayer){ 
    var finalRoute = routeLayer._layers;
    var coordsArray = Object.keys(finalRoute).map(key => {
        return finalRoute[key]
    });
    coordsArray.forEach(function(data){
        var xy = data._latlngs;
    })
```

If i proceed with code below I recieve arrays structured as I want, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53i2H.jpg), but still separated. I need to merge them somehow in one single array!

```
 var xxy = xy.map(function(obj){
        return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
            return obj[key];
        })
    })
```

Comment: what is xy?  you are only changing the last reference to your data._latlngs object set in xy, which is why you only get the last result.

Comment: @user120242 sorry mate, i updated my question. I am referencing my data to xy variable

Comment: can you give a before value and after expected result?  it's difficult to understand what you are asking for.  do you want `xxy.flat()`? or do you want `xxy = coords.concat(xxy)`?

Comment: you say separated, but you don't say what it's separated from?

Comment: I tried to flatten xxy but it separates my coordinates in single values instead keeping them in array that has lat,lng pair values...Please check last image in question linked as "see here". I get that from xxy and structure inside each array is perfect as shown on array 4. Issue is to merge these 4 arrays in single one. Hopefully this image will make it more clear

Comment: that's what I mean.  what 4 arrays are you talking about?  those 4 [lat,lng] arrays are already inside one array.  I've posted answer, is that what you wanted?

Comment: unfortunately not....I am talking about 4 big Arrays shown in image..I marked them accordingly with blue colour as 1, 2, 3, 4. First has 174 arrays, second 178, third 13 and fourth has 4 arrays. I need to merge them in one array which contains them all, 369 arrays is their sum. Therefore, I need one single array having 369 arrays inside

Comment: is that the console.log ing of output of goPark every time you run it?  will need the context of that code.  it should be something simple like just `.concat` ing the results of goPark to an array every time it calls goPark.  Another possibility is using generators, but I don't think that should be necessary for what this is doing

Comment: yea, it does. That function returns a Linestring from a server which is in this case decomposed in 4 lines instead being single, unique Linestring. Changing data type on the server doesnt do the work so I am looking for front-end concat solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a great npm package for this kinda task that i used once called [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge)
You can use it to merge one or more arrays or objects into one and control the enumerable properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need lazy loading of values only when you access it, you can turn the accumulator function into a generator (for performance).  There's other things you can do like using promises and a generator to yield values.  Though if you aren't seeing any performance issues it's unnecessary.

```
function accGoPark(reset) {
   return accFn(goPark, reset);
}

function accFn(fn, reset) {
   const accs = accFn.accs = accFn.accs || {};
   const { name } = fn;
   accs[name] = !accs[name] || reset ? [] : accs[name];
   accs[name] = accs[name].concat( fn() );
   return accs[name];
}
```

You are just setting a variable xy to a reference to your last data._latlngs iterated in your forEach loop, which is why you only get the last one.  You should just map coordsArray directly.

```
xxy = coordsArray.map(function(data){
    var obj = data._latlngs;
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
        return obj[key];
    })
})
```

Using Object.values, destructuring, and arrow functions to simplify syntax:

```
xxy = routeLayer.map( ({ _layers: { _latlngs: xy })  => Object.values(xy) );
```